# How to check if NSLayoutConstraint is animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-animation, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a custom NSLayoutConstraint subclass and I need to know if the layout constraint's `constant` property is currently animating for internal state handling. In other words, I need to distinguish between:

```
{ //no animation
    myLayoutConstraint.constant = 100;
}
```

and

```
{ //animated
    myLayoutConstraint.constant = 100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.myViewThatHasTheConstraintAttached layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [...]
    }];
}
```

So that I can handle corner cases for receiving a message on the middle of an animation. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to have a boolean wherever you want to access this and do something like...

```
{ //no animation
    theView.animatingChange = NO;
    myLayoutConstraint.constant = 100;
}

{ //animated
    theView.animatingChange = YES;
    myLayoutConstraint.constant = 100;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        [self.myViewThatHasTheConstraintAttached layoutIfNeeded];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [...]
        theView.animatingChange = NO;
    }];
}
```

The property on the view changes immediately to the "end" value of the animation. It doesn't get changed to all the intermediate values while it is animating. Just the drawing on the screen is animated.

Comment: I need to handle this implicitly, someone using the constraint class should't be setting anything externally.

Comment: Can explain more about what you are trying to achieve. The answer to the question you asked "Is it possible for a view to 'know' if it is animating?" is simple. No. It isn't possible. What are you trying to achieve though. Maybe there is another way of doing this.

Comment: I am creating a layout system that opens and closes views naturally (by swiping the headers etc) and I'm using a custom NSLayoutConstraint class that I've written to accomplish this. Currently, the system works perfectly for my own projects, but I want to take it further to become self-aware of its state and make it an open source framework. That's why I want to make this.